# Setup & scale titan/cassandra on AWS EC2 using docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, titan

I just started to use those techonologies, so appologies if my question seems/is stupid.

I want to setup a Cassandra cluster and deploy Titan over Cassandra on AWS EC2.
To do that, I found this [guide](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-Cassandra), but it is a bit of a pain to set it up, and I'm not very confident about scaling it on production.
My question is, is it possible to use a [docker to setup cassandra/titan/...](https://github.com/dkuppitz/titan-docker) (for example) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and let Elastic Beanstalk take care of scaling it?
If no, what is the easiest way to do that ?

Thanks